# Cross Site Scripting Related Query | Web Application Security

Tags: security, xss

I have read that we can filter meta characters and all that. I know all about that. In that tutorial there were written like this.

People who attack site with script, its basic format is like this.

```
<script>alert("Hi")</script>
```

So the special characters, which are used are shown below.

```
<  >  (  )  "  /
```

So in that tutorial it’s written like this you can convert this character as per your input.
Like

```
< = &bc
< = &mb
```

and so on. Then how to convert this special characters like this what should I have to write in code?

Comment: That depends on what language your code is.

Answer (score -1):

In order to accomplish what you are asking for is by using string.fromCharCode() function. the above statement can be written as follows and it works for few basic filters.

```
String.fromCharCode(60, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 62, 97, 108, 101, 114, 116, 40, 34, 72, 105, 34, 41, 60, 47, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 62)
```